# How to get an array of all possible binary numbers given a binary number of the same length

Tags: python, math, probability

- **goal**: I have a string which usually looks like this "010" and I need to replace the zeros by 1 in all the possible ways like this ["010", "110", "111", "011"]
- **problem** when I replace the zeros with 1s I iterate through the letters of the string from left to right then from right to left. As you can see in the code where I did `number = number[::-1]`. Now, this method does not actually cover all the possibilities.
- I also need to maybe start from the middle or maybe use the [permutation method](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:prob-comb/x9e81a4f98389efdf:combinations/v/introduction-to-combinations) But not sure how to apply in python.

  - mathematically there is something like `factorial of the number of places/(2)!`

```
A = '0111011110000'
B = '010101'
C = '10000010000001101'
my_list = [A,B,C]
for number in [A,B,C]:
    number = number[::-1]
    for i , n in enumerate(number):
        number = list(number)
        number[i] = '1'
        number = ''.join(number)
        if number not in my_list: my_list.append(number)


for number in [A,B,C]:
    for i , n in enumerate(number):
        number = list(number)
        number[i] = '1'
        number = ''.join(number)
        if number not in my_list: my_list.append(number)
print(len(my_list))
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected output would be for a shorter string as an example - say `010`?

Comment: @Mortz, it should be `["010", "110", "111", "011"]`, I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use separate out the zeros and then use `itertools.product` -

```
from itertools import product
x = '0011'
perm_elements = [('0', '1') if digit == '0' else ('1', ) for digit in x]
print([''.join(x) for x in product(*perm_elements)])
['0011', '0111', '1011', '1111']
```

If you only need the number of such combinations, and not the list itself - that should just be `2 ** x.count('0')`

Comment: in fact this loop taking too much time when dealing with big numbers. There must be a mathematical way related to calculate the factorial of the number of the places. I don't need this list I just need the number of combinations

Comment: @alial-karaawi, what is you goal? Just calculate amount of possible combinations?

Comment: That would just be `2 ** x.count('0')`, right?

Comment: @Mortz, or `1 << x.count('0')` :D

Comment: @Mortz
How to get all possible combinations that does not have  two consecutive ones like this? '11'

Comment: This methods tooks too long when I have numbers like '9999999'

Comment: @alial-karaawi, `9999999` is `100110001001011001111111` in binary form and contains consecutive ones, could you try to be more precised?

Comment: In fact I have another issues. it is not really related to this. However, I need a function that returns a sparse number of the input number. For example, MyFunc(75) should check if there are any town numbers that doesn't have two consecutive ones in their binary form then it should return one of these tow numbers. But, the issue is when I have big numbers

Comment: @alial-karaawi, what is "tow(n) number"?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you will definitely get other answers with a traditional implementations of combinations with fixed indexes, but as we're working with just "0" and "1", you can use next hack:

```py
source = "010100100001100011"
pattern = source.replace("0", "{}")
count = source.count("0")
combinations = [pattern.format(*f"{i:0{count}b}") for i in range(1 << count)]
```

Basically, we count amount of zeros in source, then iteration over range where limit is number with this amount of set bits and unpack every number in binary form into a pattern.

It should be slightly faster if we predefine pattern for binary transformation too:

```py
source = "010100100001100011"
pattern = source.replace("0", "{}")
count = source.count("0")
fmt = f"{{:0{count}b}}"
result = [pattern.format(*fmt.format(i)) for i in range(1 << count)]
```

---

**Upd.** It's not clear do you need to generate all possible combinations or just get number, so originally I provided code to generate them, but if you will look closely in my method I'm getting number of all possible combinations using `1 << count`, where `count` is amount of `'0'` chars in source string. So if you need just number, code is next:

```py
source = "010100100001100011"
number_of_combinations = 1 << source.count("0")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `2 ** source.count("0")`, but generally power is much more slower than binary shift, so I'd recommend to use option I originally advised.

Comment: Can you give a documentation link for `fmt = f"{{:0{count}b}}"`

Comment: @S4eed3sm, I'm kinda confused, I don't know what exact documentation link to give. Probably, [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) will fit.

Comment: Just want to point out that `<<` is the bitwise left-shift operator

Comment: @Mortz, it is, what's the problem with it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght - no problem, wanted to highlight that as it is probably not very familiar to everyone. I might be wrong though...

Comment: @Mortz, you can replace it with `2 ** count` if you like taditional math more than binary :D

Answer (score 1):

We also can use recursive solution for this problem, we iterate over string and if saw a "0" change it to "1" and begin another branch on this new string:

```python
s = "010100100001100011"

def perm(s, i=0, result=[]):
    if i < len(s):
        if s[i] == "0":
            t = s[:i]+"1"+s[i+1:]
            result.append(t)
            perm(t, i+1, result)
        perm(s, i+1, result)

res = [s]
perm(s, 0, res)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your objective you can do this to obtain the expected results.

```
A = '0111011110000'
B = '010'
C = '10000010000001101'
my_list = [A, B, C]
new_list = []
        
for key, number in enumerate(my_list):
    for key_item, num in enumerate(number):
        item_list = [i for i in number]
        item_list[key_item] = "1"
        new_list.append(''.join(item_list))
print(len(new_list))
print(new_list)
```

Comment: ERROR: `it` is not defined

Comment: Sorry I'm making a mistake. I just removed the problematic line you can test

Answer (score 0):

For each position in the string that has a zero, you can either replace it with a 1 or not.  This creates the combinations.  So you can progressively build the resulting list of strings by adding the replacements of each '0' position with a '1' based on the previous replacement results:

```
def zeroTo1(S):
    result = [S]                 # start with no replacement
    for i,b in enumerate(S):
        if b != '0': continue                         # only for '0' positions
        result += [r[:i]+'1'+r[i+1:] for r in result] # add replacements
    return result

print(zeroTo1('010'))
['010', '110', '011', '111']
```

If you're allowed to use libraries, the product function from itertools can be used to combine the zero replacements directly for you:

```
from itertools import product
def zeroTo1(S):
    return [*map("".join,product(*("01"[int(b):] for b in S)))]
```

The tuples of 1s and 0s generated by the product function are assembled into individual strings by mapping the string join function onto its output.